# How to use/store partial view (ASP.NET) in react component and use it as JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In a react component, I'm storing in `this.state.partiallogin` html elements:

```
GetPartialLogin() {
    axios.get('/account/loginpartial').then(o => {
        this.setState({ partiallogin: '<div>' + o.data + '</div>' });
    });
}
```

then in `render()` I'm using it like this:

```
render(){ return (
     <div className="col noselect">{this.state.partiallogin}</div>
);}
```

however the inner html is not rendered, it remains as text. I understood that dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not the right method to use.

REMARK1:

```
<div className="col noselect">
    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.partiallogin }}/>
</div>
```

doesn't help: I still got the html as string.

REMARK2: And when I use `this.setState({ partiallogin: <div>{o.data}</div> });`

I end up with `<div class="col noselect"><span>[object Object]</span></div>`

REMARK3:
the content of `o.data` is:

```
<form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/Logout">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a title="Manage" href="/Account/Manage">Hello XXX@YYY.com!</a></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link
                navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button></li>
    </ul>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="ZZZ"/></form>
```

NB: `o.data` content is not escapped, webpack is updating correctly code updates.

**Question: How can I ask react to take a string and render it as HTML ?**

Comment: `partiallogin: <div>{o.data}</div>`, but its not a good way, ui part should be inside render method, store the data in `partiallogin:o.data`, and create the div inside render.

Comment: Why not just use `setState` to save the data, then render it in div?

Comment: If `o.data` is HTML and you want to render it, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is pretty much your only option. If you do that, you'd better be sanitizing that HTML really well, though, otherwise you're going to be wide open to XSS attacks. As the other comments say, you'd be better off just sending data and handling the rendering on the client side.

Comment: @MayankShukla OK, done. But this doesn't solve the absence of rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to convert html as string to JSX. To solve this I needed to install `html-to-react` with

```
$ npm install --save html-to-react
```

and then call

```
GetPartialLogin() {
    var HtmlToReactParser = require('html-to-react').Parser;
    var parser = new HtmlToReactParser();
    axios.get('/account/loginpartial').then(o => {
        this.setState({
             partiallogin: parser.parse(o.data)
        });
    });
}
```

before the rendering

```
<div className="col noselect">{this.state.partiallogin}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since react component is a function, u need to change this `state` property to be a function.

```
this.setState({ partiallogin: '<div>' + o.data + '</div>' });
```

To

```
this.setState({partiallogin: ()=>(<div>{o.data}</div>)});
```

inside the `render` function call the state property component function `{this.state.partiallogin()}`.

U can checkout my [codepen](https://codepen.io/liorgrs/pen/dmLWLZ?editors=1010) example

Please note that this method is extremely unsafe and could lead to many XSS and runtime error due to the fact that u inject unsafe HTML from outside source.

Comment: In this case, actually I got nothing at all. I don't know if we can say it's better or worse.

Comment: @Soleil I've edited my answer for u to understand better, hope it helps

Comment: Now I got something, but it remains text yet.

Comment: Ok, If that is the case u will need to switch to server-side rendering, since u returning a string and not text nodes. Your about to use a seriously wrong anti-pattern if u want to dig deeper. the real issue is u will have to inject your `o.data` to the innerHTML of `this.state.partiallogin` return statement. I would highly recommend avoiding that.

Comment: Furthermore, did you see my answer ? It was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the quotes and make it into JSX

```
GetPartialLogin() {
 axios.get('/account/loginpartial').then(o => {
     this.setState({ partiallogin: <div>{o.data}</div> });
 });
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `o.data`? What is the error you're getting? Can you do `console.log(o.data)` just before `setState` and tell the output?

Comment: Sometimes webpack falls asleep and doesn't update, but here it's not the case. So, doesn't work means: the html content in `o.data` is still shown as a string.

Comment: So is the content inside `o.data` also html? or is it string?

Comment: It's a string technically (see EDIT1) but I want it to be interpreted as html in the react component, and rendered in `render()`